# Getting error when the lead is assigned back to one of the queue

Tags: apex

when lead status updated to a particluar value trigger fires and will assign lead to respective queue. This works fine for the lead owner makes lead status update but system is throwing following error "You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary." for those users even having Edit permisson on lead. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are the sharing settings for the Lead object?

Comment: on leads It is private as org wide default. Apex lead sharing rule with edit permission getting assinged for that user.

Comment: Is your apex sharing rule trigger-based, is it a separate trigger than your assignment rule?

Comment: yes it is trigger based not using assignment rule for this.

Comment: My question is not about assignment rules, it's about whether you have two triggers, one for sharing and one for this assignment rule?